# SQLite database issues only on HTC INSPIRE 4G

Tags: android, sqlite

This, to me, sounds pretty strange, but two of my application dealing with database work perfectly fine on any other handset (on all I could check), but doesn't work on HTC Inspire 4G provided by AT&T in the USA. Its running Android 2.2

The phone doesn't allow installation of third-party non-market apps thus I always have to install it through market to test, and whenever the application is run, database exception (`SQLiteException`) is thrown.
The exceptions range from not being able to read data from a table called `maincat` saying that it wasn't found, while I know its there.

In the app, the data is being provided in `raw` folder and is then copied to the internal folder when the app runs for the first time.

I am just pulling my hair off thinking where the problem may be, but I just fail to find it.

Interestingly, one of the app was an update to an older app. the older version of the app works just fine on the same device, but not the one that I edited.
I swear I never touched any of the database handling mechanism :P

Did anyone else also suffer from something similar?
Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've used the example that was available on the internet for coping the DB from a resource the code had a bug that was answered on this post.

you'll need to add in the RED lines that close out the database prior to the copy

Funny thing is most phones the code runs fine. But others will throw the table not found SQLiteException

here is the link:   [post on Anddev](http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html#p91933)

Comment: Ohh yes, I also don't close the database after calling `getReadableDatabase()` thanks man, it may work. I'll try and will post back here

Comment: It didn't work. However, your suggestions have been very valuable and I have corrected my existing code. Also, It appears that HTC Inspire isn't letting my application access internal memory, and is throwing IOException

Comment: is the phone out of free space ?

Comment: This is something that I couldn't check. Thanks for pointing it out.
But weirdly, when I changed my approach for this phone and started building the whole database from my app itself, the issue was gone. weird.